# React Native Expo errors like "None of these files exist" start happing in new

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I followed the inst here: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/typescript/ and ran `npx create-expo-app -t expo-template-blank-typescript`

I do some basic things and then try revert back to a working state and fail

And this is the 2nd time I get errors like this which nobody can give me a soln for:

```
None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/expo/AppEntry(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * node_modules/expo/AppEntry/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/photo-verify/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.70.3/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:136:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/photo-verify/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.70.3/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at /Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/photo-verify/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.70.3/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (/Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/photo-verify/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.70.3/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1137:12)
    at async Server.requestProcessor [as _processBundleRequest] (/Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/photo-verify/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.70.3/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:464:37)
    at async Server._processRequest (/Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/photo-verify/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.70.3/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:420:9)
info Launching Dev Tools...
Error: Unable to resolve module ./node_modules/expo/AppEntry from /Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/photo-verify/.:

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/expo/AppEntry(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * node_modules/expo/AppEntry/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/photo-verify/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.70.3/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:136:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/photo-verify/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.70.3/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
    at /Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/photo-verify/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.70.3/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24
    at Server._resolveRelativePath (/Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/photo-verify/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.70.3/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1137:12)
    at async Server.requestProcessor [as _processBundleRequest] (/Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/photo-verify/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.70.3/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:464:37)
    at async Server._processRequest (/Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/photo-verify/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.70.3/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:420:9)
```

Answer (score 3):

May be you've added `/node_modules/` to your `"ignore_dirs"` of your `.watchmanconfig` file. You need to remove it.
Then, clear your watchman cache with the following command : `watchman watch-del-all`.
Clear also your metro cache to be sure to rebuild your app. Just add `--clear` option to your `expo start` command, in other words, run `npx expo start --clear`.

Comment: Thanks I will check that if I ever go back to react native right now we decide to build a company on PWA